# umbraco 7 log in successful check

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco7

I'm using the built in umbraco log in system for allowing members to sign in. And my code looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm<UmbLoginController>("HandleLogin"))
{
<legend>Login</legend>

@Html.ValidationSummary("loginModel", true)

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => loginModel.Username, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Username" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => loginModel.Username, "", new { @class = "alert-danger", @role = "alert" })
<br />

@Html.PasswordFor(m => loginModel.Password, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Password" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => loginModel.Password, "", new { @class = "alert-danger", @role = "alert" })
<br />

<button class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
}
```

However Im wanting to show to the user that they have successfully logged in but I've no access to the controller class. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of [Umbraco 7.1.0](https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/6a9a1d1547e7a0508f6bed74c49ee2fd64bcf775/src/Umbraco.Web/Controllers/UmbLoginController.cs) the `UmbLoginController` redirects the user to the current page whether the log in was successful or not, that is if there's no specified **`RedirectUrl`**

You can check on the view if the log in is successful by checking `TempDataDictionary` for the item `LoginSuccess` like so:

```
@if ((bool)TempData["LoginSuccess"]) {
    <h1>Welcome user...</h1>
}
else {
    // be kind to the users and let them know what happened here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the Membershiphelper:
https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Querying/MemberShipHelper/

```
@if (@Members.IsLoggedIn())
{
    <text>Yes</text>
}
```